# Outlook VSTO - Determining whether sensitivity can be set

Tags: outlook, vsto

Am using Outlook VSTO to create a custom button that will allow users to toggle setting e-mails as private or not. When replying to an already private e-mail the e-mail should have the private button still shown but disabled as this property cannot be changed.

Originally the logic was when the following: when opening a new e-mail set the enabled property to !IsPrivate, i.e. if replying to an already private e-mail, enabled = false, if private is not set then enable the button. The issue occurs when having a draft e-mail that was set as private, when reopening it this approach will disable the button using the aforementioned logic.

Question is how can it be determined whether the private button can be enabled or disabled using the Outlook API? The message options > Sensitivity dropdown option as part of Outlook gets enabled/disabled, how does it know when to do this? If the button's enabled property can use the same logic then it should satisfy the above requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a MailItem has been saved in the Drafts folder (i.e. not Sent) or is a new MailItem, by checking the [Sent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868242%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property on the [MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

If the [Sent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868242%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property is true, the message has been sent and will be read-only when opened in a Inspector window. Otherwise the MailItem will still be editable in the Inspector window.